# Redux assign value to an object that already has values in it from another reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I've got this code:

```
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        message: "Login successful",
        cause: null,
        username: action.username,
        fullname: action.fullname,
        credit: action.credit,
        id: action.id,
        topmenutype: action.topmenutype,
        authenticated: true
      });
    case LOCATION_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        location: action.location
      });
```

So basically what I want to happen is `location` getting added to the object above. Is that possible?

Comment: I can't see a problem with your code. Do you get any errors?

Comment: There are several candidates for what you mean by "the object above".  If you mean the state object, then it looks like you've already got what you're asking for.  If something's wrong, then your question is unclear to me.

Comment: What I want to happen is that I add "location" value to the object that  LOGIN_SUCCESS returns.

Comment: You've already got that code written.  Why do you think it's not working?  And by the way, do you understand how Object.assign works?

Comment: You can also add `location` key under LOGIN_SUCCESS case just like you have added id, credit etc. It will work fine. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: When the `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action fires you will return a new object that has all the properties of the current `state` object, plus all the properties of the object you give in the `LOGIN_SUCCESS` state (with `message`, etc.).  When the `LOCATION_SUCCESS` action subsequently fires, state will already have all the properties from any previous `LOGIN_SUCCESS`, and then you'll similarly return a new object that has all the previous state properties plus your `location` property.  So your code appears to be right already.  You'll have to explain why you think it's not right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like, which exactly you did above.

```
return Object.assign({}, {
        ...state,
        location: action.location
      });
```

Comment: That code is (except for the spread operator) literally already in the question.  Not sure what you're trying to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Object.assign` and create a deep copy of object. Instead you can use spread operator. You can read more about the usage and difference between both of them [Here](https://thecodebarbarian.com/object-assign-vs-object-spread.html)

```
case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    message: "Login successful",
    cause: null,
    username: action.username,
    fullname: action.fullname,
    credit: action.credit,
    id: action.id,
    topmenutype: action.topmenutype,
    authenticated: true
  };
case LOCATION_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    location: action.location
  };
```

Comment: This is a helpful syntax tip about the spread operator, but is functionally equivalent to the code that was already posted.  What are you trying to suggest?